# How to convert a string containing the month's name to an integer?

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert a string containing the month's name to an integer that is dependent on the current locale?
I know that `somedate.strftime("%B")` can convert a date time object to a string containing the month's name according to the current locale but is there way to go backwards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strptime()` does the inverse of what `strftime()` does.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("February", "%B").month
2
```